# How do I know if Xcode version is beta?

Tags: xcode

For example, `Version 8.3.3 (8E3004b)`. How can I understand if it is a beta version or a public version?
Are there any patterns in the version number？

Comment: Goto https://developer.apple.com/download/ login with your developer account, there you can see whether it's beta version or GM. In other way, in your Xcode icon on your dock, you can see a 'beta' label on your beta version.

Answer (score 0):

Open the developer portal and access with your credential (delveloper.apple.com). After login you can select the section "Develop" from the top section and then the Download section. In the Download section you can see all the release for all software products as you can see in the image. As you can see is possible to check if your Xcode is beta or not.

Your version is not a beta version but is a release version.

[image]

Comment: Please accept my reply if this was helpful for you.